# Variable value in function name

Tags: php, function

How can I achieve the following please ?

```
function parent_func($i){
   function sample_function$i(){
      ...
   }
}

$var='25';
parent_func($var);
```

the name of sample function needs to change according to the value of $var.

Scenario:

This is a function within a class which creates sections / div on a homepage of a wordpress theme and I'm trying to add a wordpress customizer control for each class instance. I need the $i to be the ID of the section so the wordpress control has a unique ID.

Comment: What is the point of having a nested function called `function sample_function$i(){`?

Comment: Its inside a class which needs to create multiple instances of this function and include it in another class. Its besides the point tho :)

Comment: *Its besides the point tho* - I disagree, the whole idea of using a function is to not have to reproduce code.  You seem to want to spawn more code and this seems fundamentally flawed - IMHO.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with this solution because maybe there is a better way that you didn't thought of

Comment: Yep I'll look into achieving this with a class. Cheers

Comment: @mdexp updated original question

Comment: Or just pass `$i` as parameter to your `sample_function` and handle it from within the function. Or go ugly, generate the whole function as string and write it to a file that you include afterwards, something like this:
`$str = "function sample_function$i() { echo 'Hello world'; }"; file_put_contents('my-new-class.php', $str); require_once('my-new-class.php');`